# Riak-KV: how to create bucket in docker-compose file?

Tags: docker-compose, riak-kv

I try to use the original riak-kv image in docker-compose and I want on init add one bucket but docker-compose up won't start. How I can edit volumes.schemas to add bucket on init?
Original image allows to add riak.conf file in docker-compose ? If yes, then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a bucket type with a custom datatype**

I assume you want to create a bucket type when starting your container. You have to create a file in the `/etc/riak/schemas` directory with the bucket's name, like `bucket_name.dt`. The file should contain a single line with the type you would like to create (e.g. `counter`, `set`, `map`, `hll`).

You can also use the following command to create the file:

```
echo "counter" > schemas/bucket_name.dt
```

After that you have to just mount the schemas folder with the file to the `/etc/riak/schemas` directory in the container:

```
docker run -d -P -v $(pwd)/schemas:/etc/riak/schemas basho/riak-ts
```

**Creating a bucket type with default datatype**

Currently creating a bucket type with default datatype is only available if you add a custom post-start script under the `/etc/riak/poststart.d` directory.

Create a shell script with the command you would like to run. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-docker/blob/master/poststart.d/02-bootstrap-datatypes.sh).
You have to mount it as a read-only file into the `/etc/riak/poststart.d` folder:

```
docker run -d -P -v $(pwd)/poststart.d/03-bootstrap-my-datatype.sh:/etc/riak/poststart.d/03-bootstrap-my-datatype.sh:ro basho/riak-ts
```

**References**

See the whole documentation for the docker images [here](https://riak.com/posts/technical/running-riak-in-docker/index.html). The rest can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-docker).

Also, the available datatypes can be found [here](https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/latest/developing/data-types/index.html#creating-a-bucket-with-a-riak-data-type).